# How to get a parentweb(and query publishing pages) from a subsite

Tags: jsom

I'm trying to query http://rootsite/Pages from a subiste

```
//var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/");
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
        //alert(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Pages");
```

I'm getting error request failed: Cannot complete this action.Is there anything i'm oing wrong here.
If i run the code in the root site it works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

Here `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` is used to get url of root site i.e. `http://rootsite`

You can run this code from sub site as well. This will work perfectly.

```
var oListItem = "";
function getItems(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml();

    oListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsSuccess, getItemsFail);
}

function getItemsSuccess(){

    var listEnumerator = oListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(currentListItem.get_item('Title'));
    }
}

function getItemsFail(sender, args){
    debugger;
}
```